# How to get the list of available folders in a mail account using JavaMail

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I am using JavaMail API to connect to my personal account. I have list of folders (labels) in my Gmail account which I created + the default folders like Inbox, Drafts etc. How can I list all the available folders (the default and the user created)?

I can access the particular folder using this API: `Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");`. Is there any other API to get the list of folders available in a mail account?

Comment: Why on earth did you accept an answer that didn't give you the results you were looking for?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Here is the code that works. This will give you handle to all the Labels. To go deeper in a `folder`, you may perform `folder.list()` or you can use `store.getDefaultFolder().list("*")` to retrieve all the folders and sub-folders as suggested in the other answer.

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "YOURMAILID@gmail.com", "UR_P@ZZWRD");
System.out.println(store);

Folder[] f = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
for(Folder fd:f)
    System.out.println(">> "+fd.getName());
```

Output:

> >> INBOX
>   >> Personal
>   >> Receipts
>   >> Travel
>   >> Work
>   >> [Gmail]

---

*OLD ANSWER*

Please note this is not correct, it's rightly pointed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790844/how-to-get-the-list-of-available-folders-in-a-mail-account-using-java-mail/4801728#4801728) by [dkarp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/290213/dkarp)

<strike>These should do:</strike>

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Store.html#getSharedNamespaces%28%29

http://java.sun.com/products/javamail/javadocs/javax/mail/Store.html#getUserNamespaces%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: `Folder[] folders= store.getPersonalNamespaces();` when i tried this code the folders.length is always 1. But i have 8 folders in my gmail account .. 
Similarly if i tried with `Folder[] folders= store.getSharedNamespaces();` the length is always zero.

Comment: This answer is simply wrong.  This code causes JavaMail to issue [the `NAMESPACE` command](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2342#section-5), which aids in discovery of prefixes for the authenticated user's folders, other users' folders, and shared folders.  But it certainly doesn't do a folder listing.

Comment: The code you've included doesn't give the output you listed.  You need the explicit `"*"` in the `list()`, otherwise it will return only `INBOX` and the non-selectable `[Gmail]`.

Comment: @dkarp weird, I see that output with the code. I just ran that code and pasted the output and I haven't used any "*". If I do not use the "*" I get all of my Label, I have just created a new Label and I can see that appearing without (*). THis: >> Expenses
>> INBOX
>> Personal
>> Receipts
>> Travel
>> Work
>> [Gmail]. With "*", however, I see all the labels + Draft, sent, all-mails as well.

Comment: It doesn't shows the sub folder of "Inbox".

I have inbox which contains "mail1","mail2" 
I have use your code to get folder list but it only shows inbox not its subfolders.

Answer (score 71):

Sergey is close, but by default JavaMail's `list()` does a `LIST "" %`, which gives you only top-level folders.  GMail puts its system folders (All Mail, Drafts, Sent Mail, Spam, Starred, and Trash) under the non-selectable folder `[Gmail]`, so you really need to do a `LIST "" *` instead.  Otherwise, you'll just get back `INBOX`, `[Gmail]`, and your labels.

Here's some sample code that connects to GMail, fetches the folder list, and prints out the name and message count for each non-`\NoSelect` folder (i.e. the ones that aren't just hierarchy placeholders, like `[Gmail]`):

```
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
try {
    Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
    javax.mail.Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
    store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "<username>@gmail.com", "<password>");
    javax.mail.Folder[] folders = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
    for (javax.mail.Folder folder : folders) {
        if ((folder.getType() & javax.mail.Folder.HOLDS_MESSAGES) != 0) {
            System.out.println(folder.getFullName() + ": " + folder.getMessageCount());
        }
    }
} catch (MessagingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access other folders like this

```
store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Sent Mail");
store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Drafts");
```

etc.

Answer (score 0):

How about `store.getDefaultFolder().list()`? Just a guess, though.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
Folder[] folderList = store.getDefaultFolder().list("*");
```

Answer (score -1):

You can right-click on different buttons on the side panel of your mail box and inspect the names for different folders that are used in different mails.

This works for every email client. The list command works but I felt this makes the process quicker.

Comment: This is the question how to do it in a programatic way not how to do it manually...