# Can't get emails in Drafts, Spam and Trash folders from google using javax.mail

Tags: java, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I want to get emails from all folders from gmail.
From inbox, sent and other folders I receive emails successfully.
But when I try to get it from Drafts, Spam and Trash I get an exception:

```
09:51:45,622 ERROR MailRetriever.[main]getNoFlaggedMails:142 - Can't get messages: javax.mail.MessagingException: connection failure
javax.mail.MessagingException: connection failure
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.getProtocol(IMAPStore.java:742)
at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:910)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.MailRetriever.getNoFlaggedMails(MailRetriever.java:133)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.GMailServiceProcessor.processFolder(GMailServiceProcessor.java:95)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.GMailServiceProcessor.start(GMailServiceProcessor.java:80)
at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.GMailGapApp.main(GMailGapApp.java:21)
```

This is code for retrieving mails:

```
Folder folder = imapSslStore.getFolder(folderName);
folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
openedFolders.put(folderName, folder);

Flags searchFlags = new Flags(Flags.Flag.USER);
searchFlags.add(FLAG_PREFIX + READ_BY_GAP_FLAG);
Message[] messages = folder.search(new FlagTerm(searchFlags, false));
log.debug("Messages list retrieved: " + messages.length);
return messages;
```

Folder names I try to open unsuccessfully:

```
[Gmail]/Drafts
[Gmail]/Spam
[Gmail]/Trash
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest answer is that Draft, Spam and Trash are not folders but Labels in Google Mail. I am doing a Google search to validate my answer.

---

Update: After some Google search, I have found a [SO Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4790844/how-to-get-the-list-of-available-folders-in-a-mail-account-using-java-mail/4801728#4801728) which states that the `[Gmail]/*` folders are non-selectable folders.

Comment: I use imapSslStore.getDefaultFolder().list("*"); to get all folders and i get such list:
INBOX 
Personal 
Receipts 
Travel 
Work 
[Gmail] 
[Gmail]/All Mail 
[Gmail]/Drafts 
[Gmail]/Important 
[Gmail]/Sent Mail 
[Gmail]/Spam 
[Gmail]/Starred 
[Gmail]/Trash

Comment: Then try doing `folderName = "Gmail/Drafts"` and see if it works (or `folderName = "/Drafts"`).

Comment: No, now I get javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException.

Comment: @Hleb, that doesn't help. What's the cause of the exception (and message)?

Comment: 10:37:21,565 ERROR MailRetriever.[main]getNoFlaggedMails:142 - Can't get messages: javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: /Drafts not found
javax.mail.FolderNotFoundException: /Drafts not found
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.checkExists(IMAPFolder.java:388)
 at com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPFolder.open(IMAPFolder.java:1000)
 at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.MailRetriever.getNoFlaggedMails(MailRetriever.java:133)
 at ua.com.stormlabs.gap.gmail.GMailServiceProcessor.processFolder(GMailServiceProcessor.java:95)

Comment: Thank you, but it is strange, becouse I successfully get mails from [Gmail]/Important and [Gmail]/Starred.

Comment: My guess is that the `Important` and `Starred` emails are labels from the `Inbox` message, i.e. there's a reference to an inbox message from the mentioned labels.

Comment: Gmail]/Drafts is definitely selectable: C: eeeb2ce59e9340f4 SELECT "[Gmail]/Drafts" ....
S: eeeb2ce59e9340f4 OK [READ-WRITE] [Gmail]/Drafts selected. (Success)

Comment: Those folders are selectable (I just tested). Check the exact IMAP command being sent; there is a chance that something should be quoted and isn't, or vice versa.

Answer (score 5):

I have found in my Gmail account the trash folder is named "[Google Mail]/Bin" etc. and not "Gmail]/Trash".

I am in the UK and when I first opened my Gmail account it was indeed me@googlemail.com not me @gmail.com.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

```
Folder[] f = store.getDefaultFolder().list();
for(Folder fd:f){
    Folder t[]=fd.list();

      System.out.println("-------"+fd.getName()+"------");
    for(Folder f1:t)
        System.out.println("->"+f1.getName());

}
```

Comment: Please elaborate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

The following folder name :

```
[Gmail]/Spam
```

works perfectly for me. Here is my code I often use to read the spam folder using  Javamail :

```
private void readFolder(int max, boolean deletes, List<Message> result, Store store, String folderName) throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Folder folder = null;
    try {
        folder = store.getFolder(folderName);
        folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Message[] messages = folder.getMessages();
        for (int i = 0; i < messages.length && result.size() < max; i++) {
            Message message = messages[i];
            if (deletes && (!message.getFlags().contains(Flag.DELETED))) {
                message.setFlag(Flag.DELETED, true);
            }
            result.add(message);
        }
    } finally {
        if (folder != null) {
            try {
                folder.close(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Below listed are some of the default GMAIL folder names.

```
INBOX
Notes
Personal
Receipts
Work
[Gmail]/All Mail
[Gmail]/Drafts
[Gmail]/Important
[Gmail]/Sent Mail
[Gmail]/Spam
[Gmail]/Starred
[Gmail]/Trash

Code ex:
Folder mailFolder = store.getFolder("[Gmail]/Trash");
```