# get all folder list or labels in Gmail via API ( using Oauth)

Tags: gmail, google-oauth

I want to get get **all folder list (or) labels** of a certain user of **Gmail via API (using Oauth)**.

How can it be achievable ?

Currently, I can get unread gmail inbox via [feed (using Oauth)](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/gmail/gmail_inbox_feed) or certain label .

But to get a certain label related mails, first I need to get all label and want to grab a certain label related mails from all labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the list of folders is certainly doable using the GMail APIs. 
I'm assuming you have successfully authenticated using OAuth (obtained a token). 
If so, make sure to connect to the Gmail IMAP servers like [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-mail-oauth2-tools/source/browse/trunk/java/com/google/code/samples/oauth2/OAuth2Authenticator.java#74) and get a Store object.

After that, just use [this great answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4801728) to get a list of the user's folders.